# Why does fail_silently not capture an exception? What exceptions does it capture?

Tags: django

Somehow, using django 1.7 with the default email backend, I get an error: 111 Connection Refused. This is triggered as an exception, even when the fail_silently parameter is True.

The line goes like this:

```
    return send_mail(subject=u"Bienvenido a Mi CNT!",
                     message=render_to_string('micnt/mail.welcome.txt', context),
                     from_email=settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
                     recipient_list=[email_address],
                     fail_silently=True,
                     html_message=render_to_string('micnt/mail.welcome.html', context))
```

I know how to fix the excepcion (I forgot to configure certain parameters). However, there will be cases where, perhaps, the exception will be due to other reasons (e.g. I correctly specified the mail parameters, but the server got down).

Why is `fail_silently` not working? What is the "scope" of `fail_silently`? (i.e. which errors does it cover, and which errors does it let pass to the invoker?).

I would like to correctly cover the exceptions without having to:

```
try:
    return send_mail(...)
except Exception as e:
    # I want to understand what exception types will be triggered here.
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fail_silently` will only catch `SMTPException`'s when `send_mail` attempts to connect to email server (executes `get_connection`).

I like to take issues like this as an opportunity to look into the django source code, which contains all the answers:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py#L69